# Passing a delimiter value to read_csv(), such that, it is ignored for 1 of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the Titanic train dataset from Kaggle and I am trying to import it in a pandas data frame. Following is some records from the dataset:

**PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked**

- 2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs
  Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
- 3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2.
  3101282,7.925,,S

I want to import it to pandas dataframe such that the commas in the Name field values(which are included under double quotes) are not considered as a delimiter and the column is not split at that comma.
E.g.- for the second record in the example above the Name field having value- "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina" is taken as a single value and is not split at the comma between *Heikkinen* and *Miss. Laina*

Answer (score 0):

From pandas [`read_csv` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)::

> quotechar : str (length 1), optional
>
> The character used to denote the start and end of a quoted item. Quoted items can include the delimiter and it will be ignored.
>
> quoting : int or csv.QUOTE_* instance, default 0
>
> Control field quoting behavior per csv.QUOTE_* constants. Use one of QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE (3).
>
> doublequote : boolean, default True
>
> When quotechar is specified and quoting is not QUOTE_NONE, indicate whether or not to interpret two consecutive quotechar elements INSIDE a field as a single quotechar element.

So I suggest specifying quotechar in your call of read_csv.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. The issue I am facing even after using quotechar is that the data matrix is shifted to the left, i.e., in the example above, for the 2nd record, PassengerId is taken as 1(instead of 3), Survived is taken as 3(instead of 1), Pclass is "Heikkinen and Name is  Miss. Laina". Rest all the Header elements and data are aligned, owing to the disregard for quotechar here.
I am not sure as to where it is going wrong.

Comment: @AyushGiri could you let me know where you got the data from? So I can try things...

Comment: It is the train Dataset available on kaggle.com for the prediction competition-'Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster'.
Here's the link to the page- https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data
Download the 'train.csv' dataset

Comment: The issue was resolved. Apparently, when you use regex in the 'sep' argument, read_csv() ignores the 'quotechar' argument. I had used '\s*,\s*' in the sep argument and hence, the issue. 
However, I still don't get why is that so or how does one proceed when both the regex in the sep argument and the quotechar are required?
Thank you for your time!